# How do you make a Bicycle in Mutants and Masterminds?

Tags: character-creation, equipment, powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Hopefully the last time I have to ask someone a question about M&M 3e, but here it goes. I've been experimenting with a character that has a Blast Affliction that has the quirk of activating, centered on himself, whenever he's conscious inside of a motorized vehicle. So, figuring that this would be a guy that'd be in a default Hero campaign, I want to give him a camping trailer (so he can ask someone to tow his stuff/home wherever he wants, rather than going through the trouble of walking hundreds of miles at a time on multiple trips to relocate) and a bicycle (so he's still limited in how far he can move in a day, but still be able to hold down a job).

The Trailer is something that'd fit neatly as a Headquarters, but I can't seem to finagle a Bicycle as a vehicle. The closest example I've seen is a Motorcycle, but that has a motor included in that, as well as lacking some key features of a Bicycle (most importantly, the portability of a pedal bike when compared to a motor bike). Moreover, the different options that you can give a vehicle seem to be very limited based on what is presented in the rule book and absolutely don't include options for non-motorized vehicles.

That being said, **am I just being stupid, or is owning a bicycle a Power?**

Comment: ^_^ I hope you don't stop asking questions. Asking questions is how we learn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have typically (working with my GM), built a bicycle as 1 EP Equipment that grants Speed 1 rather than using Vehicle rules. That boosts my speed, and allows for Athletics checks to go faster, and also leaves the implication that I can't necessarily do it all day, that I may have to make Athletics checks to avoid getting worn out biking from place to place. Things like easy transport of the bike, maintenance, and off-roading are basically handwaved as inherent aspects of the Equipment.

Ultimately, you have to ask yourself whether the complexity is really necessary for the story you want to share with your GM and your group. Being able to get from one place to the next is generally not something that you need to worry about. Incidentally, for another low-cost "has a way to get around", a 1 EP public transit pass is far from sexy, but does the job.

Answer (score 2):

While [Sean Duggan's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/how-do-you-make-a-bicycle-in-mutants-and-masterminds/156175#156175) is very good, and the way I'd handle this in my own games, the other approach is to build the bicycle as a vehicle.

Size Medium
Strength 1
Speed 2 (3 racer)
Toughness 6
Equipment Points: 4 (5 racer)

Answer (score -6):

> [...] whenever he's conscious inside of a motorized vehicle.

Seems like that answers your question. Something not exclusively in RAW can always be negotiated with your storyteller, like reduced stats, reduced cost.

As someone who is often a storyteller, the requirement of a motorized vehicle would necessitate it not be a bicycle

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help]. I'm not an expert in M&M 3e but it seems to me that this doesn't really answer the question: "How to make a Bicycle?" You can [edit] your answer to address the question that was asked or it may be removed.